# setTimeout() returns Uncaught TypeError

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

i'm setting up the following `.hover()` function.

```
$(".portfolio_overlay").hover(function(){
 setTimeout(function(){
  $(this).fadeTo(750, 0.72, "swing", function(){});
 });
});
```

The console outputs the following error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'display' of undefined
at ae (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2
at Function.grep (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at j (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at w.fn.init.filter (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at w.fn.init.fadeTo (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
at work.js:51
```

I expect to implement a `setTimeout()` before the `fadeTo()` to give a few `ms` before the `:hover` effect happens.

What am I missing here?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you sure that error is originating from that logic?  EDIT: It may be an issue with the `this` changing inside the setTimeout callback

Comment: The `setTimeout()` adds no benefit here. You also are incorrectly referencing `this`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to access the correct \`this\` inside a callback?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20279484/how-to-access-the-correct-this-inside-a-callback)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
$(".portfolio_overlay").hover(function(){
  var that = $(this);
  setTimeout(function(){
    that.fadeTo(750, 0.2, "swing", function(){});
  });
});
```

See this [pen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dwNEZx). Previously you were trying to access `this` in a different closure, so it was not the `this` you were expecting to get.

Comment: Added explanation

Comment: You didn't explain why it's different.  You just said it is different

Comment: i believe it works because of the contextual var `that` am i right? @danny-buonocore

Comment: Yes, however not all future readers will understand what the problem is, and why this fixes it.  This answer is missing that.

Comment: @DannyBuonocore thanks a lot! for the answer and most of all for the explanation, even tho it made total sense to me as soon as i saw the var.